# Grails App: How to check if the data from previous run persisted

Tags: spring, grails, groovy, ggts

I have a grails application which I ran and persisted some data the first time. Now I want to check that database outside of the application. How can I do that?

I could potentially re-run my application and check this but I am stuck as my application stopped running and is throwing null pointer exceptions from different places. Hence the reason I want to check the data outside of application.

Here is the `DataSource.groovy` setting for the environment:

```
development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            url = "jdbc:h2:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
        }
```

As you can see, `DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE`, so I am guessing the data is not erased even if I re run the application.

On a different note, will the data still stay if I removed the present project out of context and ran another?

Apologies if this is a simple question, I am just starting out with grails. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> As you can see, DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE, so I am guessing the data is
>   not erased even if I re run the application.

`DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT` doesn't directly relate to whether or not data is erased.  See http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#do_not_close_on_exit for more details on that.

Using the settings that you have shown, when your Grails application terminates your data should still be in the database (not because of `DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT` though).  You can connect to that same database from any program using a similar JDBC url to what you have in your `DataSource.groovy` file.  You would either need to run the other application from the same directory or provide a fully qualified path to the database in your URL, like `jdbc:h2:/path/to/devDb`.

I hope that helps.